# XMPP MUC - BareJid always same in XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp

I have store group chat history when join group using below code :

```
XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *storage =[XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage   sharedInstance];

XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *xmppMessageArchivingStorage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];

XMPPMessageArchiving *xmppMessageArchivingModule = [[XMPPMessageArchiving alloc] initWithMessageArchivingStorage:xmppMessageArchivingStorage];

[xmppMessageArchivingModule setClientSideMessageArchivingOnly:YES]; 

[xmppMessageArchivingModule activate:_xmppStream];

[xmppMessageArchivingModule  addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

and fetch group history data using below code  :

```
XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *storage =[XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];

NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [storage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
NSError *error;
NSArray *messages = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

for (XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject *message in messages) {

    NSLog(@"messageStr param is %@",message.messageStr);
    NSXMLElement *element = [[NSXMLElement alloc]     initWithXMLString:message.messageStr error:nil];
    NSLog(@"to param is %@",[element attributeStringValueForName:@"to"]);
    NSLog(@"NSCore object id param is %@",message.objectID);
    NSLog(@"bareJid param is %@",message.bareJid);
    NSLog(@"bareJidStr param is %@",message.bareJidStr);
    NSLog(@"body param is %@",message.body);
    NSLog(@"timestamp param is %@",message.timestamp);
    NSLog(@"outgoing param is %d",[message.outgoing intValue]);

}
```

its working correct.

But,  BareJid always display same value when fetch data , even if other user send message or login user send message.